# Understanding a Function in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, function

I am trying to have a program that does factorial math (5*4*3*2*1 = 120) and its given range is between 1 and 9. I am having a hard time understanding what this program is actually doing. First, it uses a function, which I do not have experience with yet. But from what I understand, a function performs a given task. But, why does the ByVal argument increment each time the function is run?

```
Public Class frmFactoralMath

Public Function Factorial(ByVal intNumberIn As Integer) As Integer

    Dim intresult As Integer = 2

    If intNumberIn = 0 Or intNumberIn = 1 Then intresult = 1
    If intNumberIn < 0 Or intNumberIn > 9 Then
        Return -9999
    End If

    If intNumberIn > 2 Then
        For index As Integer = 3 To intNumberIn
            intresult = intresult * index
        Next
    End If
    Return intresult
End Function

Private Sub btnCalculate_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnCalculate.Click

    lstFactorals.Items.Clear()
    For Index As Integer = 1 To 9
    lstFactorals.Items.Add("Factorial of " & Index.ToString & " = " &      Factorial(Index).ToString)
    Next
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Yes, the function is calculating the factorial of the number it is passed as a parameter (`intNumberIn`).

Comment: a great deal might be learned by setting a breakpoint and watching the code execute line by line and variables change along with it. see [BreakPoints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/4607yxb0(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: Try to formulate a question and add it to your post.

Comment: A *Function* return a value. A *Sub* performs a task without returning a value. The general term for a Sub or Function is *Method*. Ideally, you want a function to be a *pure function*, which means it only depends on the values supplied to it and causes no side-effects: [Pure function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function).

Comment: Using breakpoints has helped significantly as it showed me what was happening based upon the intNumberIn variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Public Class frmFactoralMath ' This looks like the name of the form

''' <summary>
''' Returns the factorial of the input number
''' </summary>
''' <param name="intNumberIn">The number to calaculate the factorial of</param>
''' <remarks>Comments by http://stackoverflow.com/users/2659234/brandon-b</remarks>
Public Function Factorial(ByVal intNumberIn As Integer) As Integer

    ' Create a new variable and set it to 2
    ' This will eventually get returned
    Dim intresult As Integer = 2 

    ' If the inputted number is 0 or 1 then set the return variable to 1
    If intNumberIn = 0 Or intNumberIn = 1 Then intresult = 1 

    ' If the inputted number is less than 0 or greater than 9, then return the value "-9999" immediately and stop processing the rest of the function
    ' Basically this is a crude manner of error checking. Really it should throw an ArgumentOutOfRange exception and be handled in the calling code. 
    If intNumberIn < 0 Or intNumberIn > 9 Then
        Return -9999
    End If

    ' If the inputted number is greater than 2, then do the next thing
    If intNumberIn > 2 Then

        ' This is a for loop. The index variable, "index" is created with a type of Integer and it is saying to start at 3 and go to the inputted number. 
        ' By default the increment is a value of 1. So index will start at 3 and every time the code hits the "Next" statement below, the index value will be increased by 1.
        For index As Integer = 3 To intNumberIn

            ' Here is where the actual math happens. 
            ' Set the result to itself multiplied by the index.
            intresult = intresult * index
        Next
    End If

    ' Finally, if everything else above worked correctly, return the result value.
    Return intresult
End Function

''' <summary>
''' This sub method hadles the button click event
''' </summary>
''' <param name="sender">the object from which the event was fired</param>
''' <param name="e">Arguments of the event that was fired</param>
''' <remarks>Comments by http://stackoverflow.com/users/2659234/brandon-b</remarks>
Private Sub btnCalculate_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnCalculate.Click

    ' There is no way of knowing what this is because the code you posted lacks any reference to it.
    ' I think it's safe to assume though that it's a List(Of String) and it's clearing all the items from the list
    lstFactorals.Items.Clear()

    ' Again this is a For loop, I'm not going to copy-paste from above, just scroll up for a refresher
    For Index As Integer = 1 To 9
        ' Add a new item to the thing that I'm assuming is a list of strings
        ' The "Factorial(Index).ToString" part of this is where the function above gets called. It is being called with the index of the current for loop as the input number
        ' The .ToString method is kinda redundant though
        lstFactorals.Items.Add("Factorial of " & Index.ToString & " = " &      Factorial(Index).ToString)
    Next
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: ... or simply a ListBox to display the results in the form. I also think it's too early to introduce Exceptions to OP. An `.ToString()` is not redundant with `Option Strict On`.

Comment: In my defense, without having a declaration of `lstFactorals` to reference it could be lots of things. What I meant was the `lstFactorials.Items` is a `List(Of String)` (although technically its a collection of objects, the code is only assigning strings). However you are correct in that `lstFactorals` is most likely a listbox. Also the code presented didn't have `Option Strict On` in the code and the general default is `Option Strict Off`. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx

Comment: No offense ! :) I didn't meant that as objections, just remarks for future readers. Your answer was obviously going to be the accepted one because it answers well the question.